# Update sql column based on another column from the same row

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm using JDBC as my servlet and trying manipulate to my database.

```
id | color | description |    
1  | blue  | fasfsfafssf |
2  | red   | afsafasfasf |
```

how can I choose all rows where color=blue and change the description based on the id?
for now, i have soemthing along the lines:

```
SELECT id, description FROM table WHERE color="blue"

String description = manipulate(resultset.getInt(id)) //resultset is from executing the    query
```

Now how do i update the description of the same row with description?

hopefully that made sense

EDIT: 
The problem is that the way that description changes will be based on the ID (therefore the manipulate method).

Comment: Change description based on the ID in what way?

Comment: We're going to possibly need some more information. First, what do you expect to get - this is a big one and will help a lot. Second, are you actually trying to **manipulate** (change) the data or just change the value when you select it but leave it intact in the database?

Comment: The problem is that the way that description changes will be based on the ID (therefore the manipulate method).

Comment: That doesn't tell me _how_ it changes. What kind of change? Are you trying to do something like `id - description` or repeat the description... I'm asking **what** you expect the result to be. And if you expect the original data to remain intact. Those are two very big questions that will impact the answer.

Comment: Based how?  How will you derive the description from the id?  Please be specific so that someone can give you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `id`.  Try this.

```
update table set description = 'fluffy' where color = 'blue';
```